# Add element after navigation element title don't works like I expect

Tags: php, functions, menus

I'm currently trying to add an empty `<span>` after every item title in my navigation which has childs. So only dropdown elements. Sadly also some of my non-dropdown items getting a `<span>` inserted after the title. This is so strange. What I'm doing wrong?

```
 add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_args', 'nav_menu_modify_dropdown', 10, 3 );
    function nav_menu_add_dropdown( $args, $item, $depth ) {
        error_log( print_r( $item, true ) );
        if ( $args->theme_location === 'primary-menu' && in_array( 'menu-item-has-children', $item->classes, true ) ) {
            $args->link_after = '<span></span>';
        }

        return $args;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch of callback function names in your code. I believe, it's just a typo.

To understand the nature of your problem, we have to know, how `walker-nav-menu` uses its parameters, while traversing a menu tree. `$args` apply to **entire menu tree**. `$item` is an individual menu item.

Any changes to arguments in `$args` object, made via filters, are persistent for every next iteration of `walker-nav-menu`. Your code should be:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_args', 'nav_menu_modify_dropdown', 10, 2 );
function nav_menu_modify_dropdown( $args, $item ) {
    unset( $args->link_after );
    if ( $args->theme_location === 'primary-menu' && in_array( 'menu-item-has-children', $item->classes, true ) )
        $args->link_after = '<span></span>';
    return $args;
}
```

If there is only one menu location, you can simplify your conditional statement:

```
if ( in_array( 'menu-item-has-children', $item->classes, true ) )
    $args->link_after = '<span></span>';
```